# Rails Devise Omniauth issue with Safari and Mobile Safari on iOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, ruby, safari, devise

I am facing a weird problem when using devise with Safari (both Desktop & Mobile). When the user tries to sign in, the first time it is redirected to the home page WITHOUT a user signed in. But when I click Login again, or go to the home page in a new browser, then the user is logged in and things are working.

Everything works normally on Chrome & Firefox. The password sign in works fine on Safari too. It's just specifically the Omniauth sign in on Safari thats causing trouble.

In my OmniauthCallbacksController I have this:

```
def login_user(provider)
    @user = User.find_for_oauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      remember_me(@user)
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.to_s.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
      # current_user is present here
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
```

In my HomeController

```
def index
   if current_user
     # Should be here
   else
     # here instead
   end
end
```

What could cause something like this?